# Want to read only active cell values from excel in blueprism

Tags: blueprism

How do I extract only the available active cell values into a collection? I've got an excel file that has 10 cell values but the blue prism process is reading is entire rows from the excel. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to do that you'll need two actions:

1) The action that will return the active range

2) Action: "Get Worksheet Range as Collection"

The first action is not supplied out of the box, in standard "MS Excel VBO", but the code is really simple to write. It's should be just a code stage with one line of code

```
input: handle as number, Workbook_Name as string
output: range as string
x = GetWorkbook(handle, Workbook_Name).ActiveSheet.Selection.Address
```

(Disclaimer: I haven't tested that code)

The second one action is I think standard one, so you should be able to find it in your object.

Comment: Thanks, Andrzej. The 2nd option did work but I had to provide the cell values (for example StartCell as "A1" and EndCell as "D9". The collection was populated with this range. Let me explore the option 1 with code stage.